# getPopup() of PopupFactory not called on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, jpopup

I have extended `javax.swing.PopupFactory` class and override `getPopup()`. Also I have set as shared instance for PopupFactory.  I have put logs in getPopup() method.

On Windows I can see the logs of getPopup(). But on Mac the logs are not showing. It seems like on Mac, the `getPopup()` method is not called.

Can anyone help me why the method is not called on Mac? How can I override the `getPopup()` on Mac?

Here is my custom PopupFactory and the class in which I pack a combo box in frame.

```
 public class PopupExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new PopupFactory() {

            public Popup getPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int x, int y)
                    throws IllegalArgumentException {
                System.out.println("getPopup called...");
                return super.getPopup(owner, contents, x, y);
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new JComboBox(new String[]{"a","b","c"}));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

On Windows I can see the message "getPopup called..." in the console when I click on combobox to open. But on Mac it didn't show the message.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Sorry for that. I am new on stackoverflow. I have edited the question.Thanks :)

Comment: What you have posted is uncompilable code snippets.  Please follow the link and *read* about the MCVE.

Comment: not an SSCCE/MCVE, but with code line popup.show();

Comment: Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int x, int y);

Comment: Thanks guys. I have posted the whole code so that it can be helpful to reproduce the issue.

Comment: where is popup.show();

Comment: popup.show() will be called when I click on jcombobox. I want to do some changes for combobox popup. So I can write code in getPopup() method as it will be called when jcombobox is clicked.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6f8T27xCt6dbmdIZUd6aVBzSjQ/edit?usp=sharing

You can see from above image that on windows the message is displayed in the log when we open the combobox.